# iOS SA_OAuthTwitterEngine authenticating, but not posting, and no delegate callbacks

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth

I had `SA_OAuthTwitterEngine` seemingly working fine in my iOS app, but a couple of months ago, it stopped working (EDIT: not working in iOS 4 or iOS 5, and no code changed in the app prior to the malfunction). It is authenticating and storing creds fine, and passing them to my database service just fine. When I attempt to post a Tweet, everything logs fine as if it's going through the proper process. All tokens and usernames, etc. getting passed correctly. However, I am seeing no posts on Twitter. I am using a date stamp in the post and have tried this on two different user accounts without seeing a single post from either account. Interestingly, the **`MGTwitterEngineDelegate`** callbacks (`requestSucceeded:` and `requestFailed:`) are not being called. I put breakpoints in MGTwitterEngine's `connection:didReceiveResponse:`, `connection:didReceiveData:`, and `connection:didFailWithError:` to see if it was just a delegate assignment issue, but those breakpoints were never reached, so the app is seemingly getting no response from Twitter, despite the fact that I can log a Connection Identifier returned from the engine's sendUpdate: method every single time. If I can get the delegate to receive the connection's response, maybe I'll see an error. SO that's what I have been banging my head on all day. Any help would be appreciated.

Code here:

```
- (void)postTweetToTwitter 
{
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:TWITTER_USER]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ShowSettings" object:nil];
        return; //Makes sure user data is stored in NSUserDefaults before continuing, if not, settings will prompt for authentication
    }

    NSString *formattedDateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date] dateStyle:kCFDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:kCFDateFormatterNoStyle];
    NSString *tweetMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: Tweet message goes here.",  formattedDateString];  

    if(!_engine){
        _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
        _engine.consumerKey    = kOAuthConsumerKey;
        _engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;      
    }

    UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];    
    if (controller)
        [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
    else {
        NSString *twitterConnectionIdentifier = [_engine sendUpdate:[NSString stringWithString:tweetMessage]];  
        NSLog(@"Twitter Connection Identifier : %@", twitterConnectionIdentifier);
    }
}

- (NSString *) cachedTwitterOAuthDataForUsername: (NSString *) username {      
    NSString *authData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:TWITTER_USER];
    if (authData) {
        return authData;
    } else return [NSString stringWithString:@"No Twitter Data"];
    //This just won't do anything, but we avoid this case in the first if statement above.   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same type problem then found out that my twitter account was blocked/banned for posting. May be you have the same problem.